# Symfony2 session for all subdomains

Tags: symfony, session, subdomain

The website I am building has a subdomain per user. The default domain is www.acme.com, my own page would (for example) be marcel.acme.com. Another users pages are under johndoe.acme.com. Now the following happens:
- www.acme.com shows me as logged in.
- marcel.acme.com shows me as logged in.
- johndoe.acme.com shows me as anon.

Within my config.yml I did set

`framework:`
    `session:`
       `cookie_domain: .acme.com`

Firewall is defined for ^/ and uses both form_login (FosUserBundle) and oauth. Both have same behavior.

Login on www.acme.com does redirect to marcel.acme.com, so probably that is why both marcel and www do work, but how can I get all subdomains to work?

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check 
        oauth:
            login_path: /login
            failure_path: /login
            check_path: /login
            use_forward: false
            default_target_path: /mytracker
            provider: fos_userbundle
            resource_owners:
                facebook: /login/check-facebook
            oauth_user_provider:
                service: my_user_provider
        anonymous:    true        
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /
```

Version of Symfony is 2.6.5

Comment: Could you share your firewall configs from your `security.yml`?
Also, which version of Symfony are you using?

Comment: Added the answers to my original post!

Answer (score 3):

Seems I managed to solve it. Within my config I added:

```
session:
    cookie_lifetime: 0
    save_path: %kernel.root_dir%/var/sessions
    cookie_domain: .acme.com
    name: SFSESSID
```

Furthermore I added to my security:

```
remember_me:
    key:      "%secret%"
    lifetime: 31536000
    path:     /
    domain:   .acme.com
```

That last part should not be needed bt I want to implement remember_me functionality anyway. Thanks for thinking along, maybe someone is helped by this.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't able to check this sooner.
I was going to suggest you to set the session `name` parameter, but even that was not needed for me to get this to work (I've tried with and without it).
Also, the `remember_me` section at the `main` firewall should not be necessary as you said.

Anyway, glad you got it working. :)