# Symfony 4 : Anonymous token in public page even after logged in

Tags: php, symfony, security, symfony4

On my website, I have 3 sections : Admin, Members and Public. The Admin section is only reachable through "gestion.%domain%", and must have an Admin User. This section works great.

For the Members section, it is reachable through "membre.%domain%", and must have a Member User. This also works great.

The problem comes to the Public section. Every part of this section is accessible either anonymously or logged in with a Member User. When logged in, the top menu will change a bit to show more option (kinda like any shopping website).

So I've configured my security settings as follow :

```
security:
    providers:
        membre_provider:
            id: App\Security\Provider\MembreProvider
        manager_provider:
            id: App\Security\Provider\ManagerProvider

    encoders:
        App\Entity\Utilisateur: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_MEMBRE: [ROLE_NON_MEMBRE]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN]
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_EDITEUR]

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        admin:
            host: 'gestion.%domain%'
            pattern: .*
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: admin_login
                check_path: admin_login
            access_denied_url: admin_access_denied
            provider: manager_provider
            logout:
                path:   admin_logout
                target: admin_login
        main:
            pattern: .*
            anonymous: true
            form_login:
                login_path: membre_login
                check_path: membre_login
            access_denied_url: membre_login
            provider: membre_provider
            user_checker: App\Security\MembreUserChecker
            logout:
                path:   membre_logout
                target: index
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
                name: 'remember_me_main'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path:     /
                always_remember_me: true
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/connexion, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, host: 'membre.%domain%' }
        - { path: ^/demande_reinitialisation, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, host: 'membre.%domain%' }
        - { path: ^/reinitialisation, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, host: 'membre.%domain%' }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_NON_MEMBRE, host: 'membre.%domain%'}
        - { path: ^/connexion, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, host: 'gestion.%domain%' }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_EDITEUR, host: 'gestion.%domain%'}
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
```

As you can see, I have the admin context and the main context. The main context is shared between the "Members" section and the "Public" section. And it does work as intended when testing it (in the "Security" tab of the profiler, both shows as "main" context)

The problem is when I try to get the logged in user infos in the public section, I always get the anonymous token (it even shows the anonymous token in the profiler), but when I'm in the "Members" section, I can get the logged in user correctly.

I'm completely lost there...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have managed to solve my issue. The problem came from the session handling. Since I have multiple sub-domains, the session wasn't shared between them, so my public section wasn't aware that the user was logged in in the member section.

The only thing I had to configure was the session parameters in `framework.yml` :

```
session:
    handler_id: ~
    cookie_domain: '.%domain%'
    name: 'MYAPPSESSID'
```

EDIT : This SO answer helped me in finding and solving the problem : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29850083/1907465